# php exec python script that writes file

Tags: php, permissions, exec, file-permissions

I need to execute a python script that writes a file in the same directory.

test.py :

```
print 'Hi! I was executed'
```

test2.py :

```
filename = 'sample.txt'
target = open(filename,'a')
target.write("Something Something")
target.close()
```

Php script:

```
<?
    exec('python test.py',$output1,$ret1);
    exec('python test2.py',$output2,$ret2);
?>
```

The first exec works fine but the second script does not, the return var $ret2 is 1.
Both the commands work perfectly fine in the terminal. I guess it is a permission issue as php scripts are executed as 'nobody'.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try to give full path for filename = 'sample.txt'

Comment: like filename = '/home/pranjal/sample.txt'

Comment: Ok I will add this as an answer then

Comment: @SajithNair I have another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22230525/php-exec-python-script-that-imports-numpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to give full path for `filename = 'sample.txt'`

For e.g.

```
filename = '/home/pranjal/sample.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a COM:

```
<?php
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("[Your command here]", 0, false); 
?>
```

Mind you this will not work wonders running in a Linux server.

Also please consider that you are allowing your script to execute code, please make sure it's all safe when it needs to be :)

```
escapeshellarg()
escapeshellcmd()
```

Will remove the commands that you don't want to run.