# php exec python script that imports numpy

Tags: php, python, exec, python-import

I need a php script to execute a python script. Now the python code looks like this:

test.py

```
import sys
try:
    import numpy
    print 'Numpy was loaded'
except:
    print 'Could not Load Numpy'
```

All the following commands print 'Numpy was loaded':

```
$python test.py
$python2.7 test.py
```

PHP Script:

```
exec('python test.py',$output,$ret);
var_dump($output);
```

The PHP script works if the line 'import numpy' is removed.

I have tried the following things:

1. Use absolute path in php script : exec("/usr/bin/python /home/pg/test.py"), 
   exec("python2.7 test.py")
2. Added absolute path of pwd and numpy using 
   sys.path.append("path/to/numpy/dir where  **init**.py is present")

It can be a user permission issue as well, but I have no idea.

### EDIT

The exact error that python gives is :

```
"from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite"
  ImportError: /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_4.2.0' not found (required by /lib/libgfortran.so.3
```

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223249/calling-python-from-php-fails-when-import-numpy

Comment: @SajithNair I have made an edit